# Would it work and be faster if I call function in OpenCV GPU module in my kernel function?

Tags: opencv, cuda

OpenCV has a `gpu. GPU-accelerated Computer Vision` module (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/gpu.html). There are many functions which is already use GPU techniques. So I can directly use the function OpenCV applies. But I wonder whether it would be faster if I write my own kernel and in each kernel I call function of OpenCV GPU module. This is in the case I have many images. To handle each image I call OpenCV funtion in GPU module. Then it would be parallel-nested-parallel.

Comment: Have you tried your approach?

Comment: @IanMedeiros, Because I concern how to set the number of block and concern the memory issue, I have not tried.

Comment: You're not going to be able to call an OpenCV function from a CUDA kernel.

Comment: @RobertCrovella,thank you for your comment. Do you mean CUDA do not allow to use other functions except the C++ code you write yourself?

Comment: Routines in host libraries cannot be used in device code.  It's understood that a `cv::gpu` routine appears to be a "GPU" function, but it ultimately represents a host function, called from host code, that causes some activity to occur on the device.  Such functions compiled for, and designed to be used in host code cannot be used in device code, directly.   The reason is similar to why you cannot use `<string>` functions directly in device code.  They are using routines in a library compiled for the host.

Comment: If you're looking for the fastest method for your problem, you can consider benchmarking the fft-convolution too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear to me, but I would like to say this: it's impossible to say which would be faster, unless somebody already implemented that same algorithm using the approach you have in mind, and then shared a report about the benchmark tests.

There's a number of factors involved:

- **It depends on the type of operation you are trying to implement**: techniques that have a high arithmetic intensity are better fit for GPUs for sure, however, not all problems can be modeled for GPUs.
- **The size of the input images matter**: wasting time sending data from RAM to the GPU might not compensate in the end, so running the algorithm on the CPU can be faster for small images.
- **The model/power of the CPU/GPU**: if the computer has a really crappy GPU, then it's probably better to run the algorithms on the CPU.

What I'm saying is: don't assume OpenCV GPU's module will always run it's algorithms faster than the CPU you got. Test it, measure it! The only way to know for sure is through experimentation and benchmark.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It sounds in-confident. I learn GPU with the hope - make my experiment faster and faster ....